# Error message when starting terminal -- .zshrc linked

Tags: macos, terminal, zsh, zshrc

I wanted my MacOS terminal to have a different color for outputs from the color on the command line. Like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FEPXO.png), but not only for `ls` but for essentially every single output.

So I put this in my .zshrc:

```
preexec() { 
    tput setaf 15
    :
}
preexec_invoke_exec() {
    [ -n "$COMP_LINE" ] && return
    local this_command=`HISTTIMEFORMATE= history 1 | sed -e "s/^[ ]*[0-9]*[ ]*//"`;
    preexec "$this_command"
}

trap 'preexec_invoke_exec' DEBUG
```

And it's worked beautifully (other than the annoying command line lag) for over a year, until just recently whenever I start Terminal I get this error:

```
preexec_invoke_exec:fc:3: no such event: 1
preexec_invoke_exec:fc:3: no such event: 1
preexec_invoke_exec:fc:3: no such event: 1
preexec_invoke_exec:fc:3: no such event: 1
preexec_invoke_exec:fc:3: no such event: 1
preexec_invoke_exec:fc:3: no such event: 1
(eval):1: bad pattern: ^[[97m#
```

[Here's the actual image.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HDvzM.png)

Not really sure what's wrong. According to some other posts, it may have something to do with $HISTORY not having a length, but nothing has been able to fix it so far and I there's not many similar posts. Anyone know what's going on here? Or maybe someone knows a more intuitive way to change the output color? Thanks in advance!

Comment: What's the purpose of unsetting `HISTTIMEFORMATE` when invoking `history`? This variable does not have any special meaning for zsh anyway.

Comment: For debugging, I would log the content of the variable `this_command` to a file, to see what it really contains. The _no such event_ error makes me wonder, whether recording the history is turned on at all. Therefore, I would for debugging also log the output of a plain `history` command to a file, just to see that we do have a history.

Answer (score 0):

`history 1` outputs the whole history, starting with event 1. In your case, you need only the last element of the history, which would be `history -1`.

To find the most recent command, I would do a

```
local h=( $(history -1) )
local this_command=$h[2,-1] # Strip the event number
[[ -n $this_command ]] && preexec $this_command
```